# Using cscript in for statements

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

***ANSWERED AND FIXED***
I have the code:

```
Dim stringa, stringb
stringa = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
stringb = Split(stringa, ".")
WScript.Echo "." & Replace(stringb(UBound(stringb)),"`"," ")
```

In a vbs file, coupled with the code:

```
set pth=%~dp0
set /p patha="File path? "
for /F %%G in ('cscript.exe "%pth%GETEXT.vbs" "%patha%"') do set ext=%%G
```

But whenever I run it, the batch file closes when it reaches the for statement. It works fine when I set `patha` to `C:\Users\Username\somefile.txt`, but crashes when I use `C:\Users\Username\Desktop\folder\fol der\f older\somefile.txt`, does anyone have a fix or reason for the crash?

**EDIT:**
Fixed by adding `//nologo`: `'cscript.exe //nologo "%pth%GETEXT.vbs" "%patha%"'`

Comment: may be you need to use `'cscript.exe ""%pth%GETEXT.vbs"" ""%patha%""'`?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: does `%pth%` have "\" as last character? try `"%pth%\GETEXT.vbs"`. also what's the error message?

Comment: Yes, `%pth%` returns `C:\Users\Username\`.

Comment: And using your code `%ext%` returns `Input`.

Comment: have a go with `'cscript.exe //nologo "%pth%GETEXT.vbs" "%patha%"'`

Comment: @PatricK answer so I can upvote and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing it myself, it was the cscript option `//nologo needed, otherwise you get the first 2 lines of banner as screenshot below:

```
'cscript.exe //nologo "%pth%GETEXT.vbs" "%patha%"'
```

[image: cscript]